# Why I cant access a new attribute I created in a propertydrawer script from mono script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class GapRangeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    float minRange;
    float maxRange;
    float sensitivity;

    public GapRangeDrawer(float minRange, float maxRange, float sensitivity)
    {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.sensitivity = sensitivity;
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        if (property.propertyType == SerializedPropertyType.Float)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);
            EditorGUI.Slider(position, property, minRange, maxRange, label);
            property.floatValue = RoundValue(property.floatValue);
            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }
        else
        {
            EditorGUI.LabelField(position, label.text, "Use [GapRangeDrawer] with float values only!");
        }
    }

    private float RoundValue(float value)
    {
        return Mathf.Round(value / sensitivity) * sensitivity;
    }
}
```

then in a mono script:

```
public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cubePrefab;
    [Gap
```

but GapRangeDrawer is not exist.

i tried to create my own attribute but I can't access it.
i wanted to make a custom range attribute.

the propertydrawer script is under Assets > Editor folder but still I can't access the new attribute.

Comment: Thats not how Ive seen the PropertyDrawer used, normally it is tagged to show a specfic property type - and isnt an attribute, an attribute is different...

Comment: Drawer != the actual attribute ... in order to implement an attribute it needs to be derived from `Attribute` (or in unity also `PropertyAttribute` which already comes with certain limitations like applicable to fields only etc)

Answer (score 2):

Apply the CustomPropertyDrawer attribute to your PropertyDrawer class.  Make sure this class is defined inside of an Editor folder.

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GapRangeAttribute))]
public class GapRangeDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    ...
}
```

You also need to create a `PropertyAttribute`.  Unity provides an example further down the [Property Drawer Documentation Page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PropertyDrawer.html).

Your attribute will look something like this.

```
public class GapRangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute
{
    float minRange;
    float maxRange;
    float sensitivity;

    public GapRangeAttribute(float minRange, float maxRange, float sensitivity)
    {
        this.minRange = minRange;
        this.maxRange = maxRange;
        this.sensitivity = sensitivity;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it in the way you intended.

```
[GapRange(0, 100, 3)]
public float someValue;
```

Comment: The GapRangeAttribute : PropertyAttribute should be in his own module file script? i created that in the same Editor folder and added the [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(GapRangeAttribute))] to the propertydrawer and still can't access it in the mono script.  I type [gap  but it's not exist.

Comment: The GapRangeAttribute needs to be outside of the editor folder.